# Some questions from Arhangel'skii-Buzyakova

Tags: general-topology

The proposition 2.6 of [On linearly Lindelöf and strongly discretely Lindelöf spaces_ by Arhangel'skii and Buzyakova](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1999-127-08/S0002-9939-99-04783-8/):

> Let $X$ be a linearly lindelof Tychonoff space of countable tightness such hat $|X|\le 2^\omega $ and $W(X)\le 2^\omega$. Then $Ch(X)\le 2^\omega$.

The proposition 3.4 of [On some properties of lindelof _ by Arhangel'skii and Buzyakova](http://www.topology.auburn.edu/tp/reprints/v23/tp23201.pdf) is almost the same as proposition 2.6 above:

> Let $X$ be a linearly lindelof Tychonoff space such hat $|X|\le 2^\omega $ and $W(X)\le 2^\omega$ and $F(X)\le \omega$. Then $Ch(X)\le 2^\omega$.

Their proofs are same in the papers. Could somebody tell me that what is the use of countable tightness in the proposition 2.6 and the use of $F(X)\le \omega$ in the proposition 3.4? In all the proof of the paper, the authors didn't mention these condition although they were listed in the Proposition.

Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proofs of Proposition $2.6$ in the first paper and Proposition $3.4$ in the second paper depend on Proposition $2.5$ of the first paper and the identical Lemma $3.3$ of the second paper. This preliminary result has $F(Y)\le\omega$ as one of its hypotheses, and if you check the proof in the first paper, you’ll see that this hypothesis is actually used, when Lemma $2.3$ is appealed to.

It only remains to show that the hypothesis $t(X)=\omega$ in Proposition $2.6$ of the first paper implies that $F(X)\le\omega$. Suppose that $\langle x_\xi:\xi<\omega_1\rangle$ is a free sequence in $X$. If $x\in\operatorname{cl}\{x_\xi:\xi<\omega_1\}$, then by the countable tightness of $X$ we must have $x\in\operatorname{cl}\{x_\xi:\xi<\eta\}$ for some $\eta<\omega_1$, and hence $x\notin\operatorname{cl}\{x_\xi:\eta\le\xi<\omega_1\}$. Thus, $\{x_\xi:\xi<\omega_1\}$ has no complete accumulation point. But it’s known that if $X$ is linearly Lindelöf, and $\kappa$ is an uncountable regular cardinal, then every subset of $X$ of cardinality $\kappa$ has a complete accumulation point. Thus, $X$ has no free sequence of length $\omega_1$, and $F(X)\le\omega$.